# Trying to understand part of an existing TCL script using Regular Expression

Tags: regex, tcl

I've been researching this as I am trying to begin working with TCL in my work with routers in my shop.  We have a tech who is writing scripts I have access to and so I am trying to learn from his work.

I came across the following section at the beginning of a script that I've been trying to understand and have made little headway on.  I was hoping you can help with any explanation at all.

The section sets the prompt, and creates prompt settings used later in the script.

```
set prompt "(%|#|\\$) $"      ;# default prompt
catch {set prompt $env(EXPECT_PROMPT)}
set spec "(,|%|\\)|\\(|;|:|\\.|\\*|\[|\]| |/|{|}|\\||\\$|\"|\'|\\\\|-)"
```

Later on, the value of the variable spec is used as follows:

```
set cmd "show clock"
regsub -all $spec $cmd "_" cmde
```

So I would really like to know what's happening but my 'web foo' is failing me completely on this.

Thanks!
    Marc

Answer (score 2):

The regsub command is converting a set of "special" characters to underscores. The `spec` regex might be easier to comprehend (and easier to read) like this:

```
set spec {[][,%)(;:.* /{}|$"'\\-]}
```

<sub>brackets, comma, percent, parentheses, semicolon, colon, dot, star, space, slash, braces, pipe, dollar, double-quote, single-quote, backslash, hyphen -- (if you want to put brackets in a character class, you have to place the closing bracket as the first character)</sub>

Extrapolating a bit, if the goal is to change all non-alphanumeric characters to underscores, do it like this

```
regsub -all {\W} $cmd "_" cmde
```

`\W` is a regular expression shorthand for "non-word-characters"

http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm

Another way to set the prompt variable, and how I would write it:

```
if {[info exists env(EXPECT_PROMPT)]} {
    set prompt $env(EXPECT_PROMPT)
} else {
    set prompt {[%#$] $}
}
```

If you're learning Tcl, use the [Tcl Tutorial](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html).

Comment: First, thank you "very much" for your response!!                 Second, since it can be done in such a readable way, what does all the original author's code mean??  To someone like me, that just looks bizarre.

Comment: The regex pipe symbol `|` means "match either this expression or that expression" (see http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)  so what the author wrote was "match a comma OR a percent OR a close parenthesis OR ...". Since each alternative is a single character, a character class is the more appropriate container. Also the author apparently was unaware of Tcl's braces `{}` quoting mechanism, so there is quite a lot of backslashitis.